# ReactJS - getAttribute return null

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem with getAttribute() in my React code.

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
        let selectM = event.target.getAttribute("data-minister_name");
        console.log(selectM);
    };

<List dense sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}>
                        {listMiniters.map((c) => (
                            <ListItem
                                key={c.label}
                                disablePadding
                                onClick={handleChange}
                                data-minister_name="{c.label}"
                            >
                                <ListItemButton>
                                    <ListItemAvatar>
                                        <Avatar
                                            alt={`Avatar n°${c.label + 1}`}
                                            src={`https://flagcdn.com/w20/${c.code.toLowerCase()}.png`}
                                        />
                                    </ListItemAvatar>
                                    <ListItemText id={c.label} primary={`Line item ${c.label + 1}`} />
                                </ListItemButton>
                            </ListItem>
                        ))}
                    </List>
```

It return to my

> null

I don't understand where come from the problem...? Could you help my please ?

I'm using MUI.

Comment: If you console.log `event.target` can you see the attribute `data-minister_name`?

Comment: You right @Magofoco, I get a Div without my data-attribute. I didn't except that. Do you know why it doesn't appear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `event.target` will be the element that was actually clicked which isn't, necessarily, the same as the element to which the event handler was bound.

The `ListItem` has a number of descendant elements which will intercept the click and be the `event.target`.

[Use `event.currentTarget` instead.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Comment: If I code : ```event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-minister_name")``` it return {c.label}. That it is my code, but not the value I add in.
Do you have more tips please ?

Comment: `="{c.label}"` — you're assigning a string with that value. If you don't want a string, don't use quotes.

Comment: OMG you totaly right. Thar work now.
Basic mistake at the end of the day. Thank you very much to your help.

Answer (score -1):

Please try without **'_'** in your attribute name.

Altrernatively try with  e.target.attributes.getNamedItem("aatribute-name").value;

Comment: I tried, but that change nothing TT